# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | 0 < f(x) \leq 1 \}$ an open or closed subset?

Tags: real-analysis

Would the below be an acceptable answer for the above?

Attempt:

Let $X = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | f(x) > 0\}$ and $y \in X$. Then $\exists \delta$ such that if $|x-y| < \delta$ then 
$$|f(x) - f(y) | < f(y) \implies -f(y) < f(x) - f(y) < f(y) \implies 0 < f(x).$$
Hence, for every $y \in X$, we can define an open ball $B_\delta (y) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | \left| x - y \right| < \delta \}$ such that $B_\delta (y) \subset X$. Hence, $X$ is open. 
\item Let $X = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | 0 < f(x) \leq 1 \}$, $y \in X$ such that $f(y) = 1$, and $B_\delta(y)=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | \left|x-y\right| < \delta \}$. Now, $B_\delta(y) \not\subset X$ for any $\delta$ since by the continuity of $f$, $\exists x \in B_\delta(y)$ such that $f(x) > 1$. Hence, $X$ is not an open subset.

Let $y$ be a limit point of $X$. Then there exists a sequence $ \{ x_n \} \in X$ such that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = y \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(y). $$
Now, let $y=0$ and define $\{ x_n \} \in X$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 0$. Since $0$ is a limit point of $X$ and $0 \not\in X$, $X$ is not closed.

Hence, $X$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: Without looking, your proof can't be right; if $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ then your set is both open and closed. In general, it needn't be either, but for some $f$ it could be either open or closed or both.

Comment: By giving a few selected examples ($4$ to be precise, none more difficult than a polynomial function of degree${}\leq2$), you can see that any combination of "$X$ is open" and "$X$ is closed" is possible. In short, one just cannot tell from the hypotheses alone what is the case; this spares you the effort of trying to prove anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that :$$\{x:0<f(x)\leq 1\}=\{x:0<f(x)< 1\}\cup \{x: f(x)=1\}=[f^{-1}(0,1)]\cup f^{-1}(1)$$

As your $f$ is continuous your $f^{-1}(0,1)$ is always open....

As your $f$ is continuous your $f^{-1}(1)$ is always closed....

If you are looking for the union to be closed(open) you need that open(closed) part to be whole $X$..

So, In general it need not be closed or open......

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)\equiv-1$ is a counterexample, hence your proof needs some small corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x$. Clearly this function is continuous. But $f^{-1}(\,(0,1]\,)=(0,1]$. The set $(0,1]$ is neither open nor closed under the standard Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.